# Heroku with tokbox api on android (Kotlin) create new session

Tags: android, kotlin, heroku, tokbox

I am trying to create a new session on an android application using heroku and tokbox api, (ignore that the code is incomplete it does not matter):

```
    val reqQueue: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity)
    reqQueue.add(JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            "https://APP_NAME.herokuapp.com" + "/session", null,  object: Response.Listener<JSONObject>,
            Session.SessionListener {
            override fun onResponse(response: JSONObject?) {
                try {
                    API_KEY = response!!.getInt("apiKey")
                    SESSION_ID = response.getString("sessionId")
                    TOKEN = response.getString("token")
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "API_KEY: $API_KEY")
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "SESSION_ID: $SESSION_ID")
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "TOKEN: $TOKEN")
                    val session = Session.Builder(activity, "$API_KEY", SESSION_ID).build()
                    session.setSessionListener(this)
                    session.connect(TOKEN)
                } catch (error: JSONException) {
                    Log.d("Main", "Web Service error: " + error.message)
                }
```

I want to make it so that every time the user runs this activity they create a new session id for tokbox, but everytime I run it, it just reuses the same one.  How do I solve this???

Comment: It looks like your server just sends the same session ID. Therefore I assume it's a problem in your server code.

Comment: What about Forcing a client endpoint to disconnect from a session?
https://tokbox.com/developer/rest/#forceDisconnect